# Angularjs $http works on localhost but retrieves 404 when on host [ wordpress ]

Tags: php, angularjs, wordpress

I have this code which retrieves/saves/deletes/updates data and it works perfectly on localhost but on a normal host it just retrieves 404 page.

Angular code

```
$http({
    method : "REQUEST",
    url    : "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    params : { action: "pl", reqType: "createRole", name: role.name }
}).then( function successAjax( data ) {
        console.log( data );
}, function errorAjax( data ) {
        console.log( data );
});
```

And on the php file of the wordpress plugin:

```
 add_action( "wp_ajax_pl", "reqHandler" );
 function reqHandler( ) {
         $_pl_class = new Pl_class( );
         switch( $_REQUEST[ 'reqType' ] ) :
                 case "getRoles":
                        echo json_encode( $_pl_class -> get_role( ) );
                 break;
                 case "deleteRole":
                        echo json_encode( $_pl_class -> delete_role( $_REQUEST[ "roleId" ] ) );
                 break;
                 case "updateRole":
                        echo json_encode( $_pl_class -> update_role( $_REQUEST[ "roleId" ], $_REQUEST[ "roleName" ] ) );
                 break;
                 case "createRole":
                        echo json_encode( $_pl_class -> create_role( $_REQUEST[ "name" ] ) );
                 break;
         endswitch;
         exit;
 }
```

The return in host:

```
Object { data: "<!DOCTYPE html>"[…], status: 404, headers: gd/<(), config: Object, statusText: "Not Found" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by removing slash from start of url

```
 url    : "wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
```

You can also share url of the site where it is causing problem.

Comment: It's in wp-admin so kind of can't tried making an abs path still didn't work and the slash didn't too

Comment: plz share the link of the website where you are trying.

Comment: It's in admin panel can't quite show you because you need administration rights. Maybe a problem is where I put the php handler function ? It's in one of class files, I didn't quite knew where to put it

Comment: check network tab in developer tools and try to look at what is the path that is being created.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the `method : 'REQUEST'` from the $http request and now it works. Don't know the logic behind this tho.